# Swift: Trying to target Class method as selector for NSTimer

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a class method of my class `Sentence` as the `selector` for my `NSTimer`. Here is my method, which incidentally is also the one which makes the `NSTimer` call :

```
func playEvent(eventIndex : Int){
    if (eventIndex < 2){
        let currEvent = self.eventArray[eventIndex]
        currEvent?.startEvent()
        let nextIndex = eventIndex + 1
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval((currEvent?.duration)!, target: self, selector: "playEvent:sentence:", userInfo: NSNumber(integer: nextIndex), repeats: true)
    }
    else if (eventIndex==2){
        self.eventArray[eventIndex]?.startEvent()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "sentenceDidFinish", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    else{
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Do I need to write `self.playEvent` in the `selector` or is that impossible to do?

Here is the whole class context: 
https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/e56b0b6ebedbe4474d01

Comment: If your sentence object is conform to AnyObject, you can just put it in userInfo. userInfo is not necessary to be a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question/code is hard to follow, please add the class definition and reword the question.

**UPDATE**

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {

    class func someClassMethod() {
        print("called class method")
    }

    func someInstanceMethod() {
        print("called instance method")
    }

    func setupInstanceMethodTimer() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("someInstanceMethod"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}

// setup timer for class method
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: SomeClass.self, selector: Selector("someClassMethod"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

// setup timer for instance method
let someInstance = SomeClass()
someInstance.setupInstanceMethodTimer()
```

Comment: Hmmm. Still getting the same error in this context: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1561456669af5eb037e1

Comment: it looks like you want to call an instance method, not a class method. i will update my answer

Comment: in the gist you are calling a selector that doesn't exist ```Selector("playEvent:sentence:")```

Comment: Currently getting this error: `unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103ea6a80
2016-02-03 13:48:36.479 kleinGross[28572:1617588] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[kleinGross.Sentence playEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103ea6a80'`

Comment: the gist linked above is still the same. you are getting closer though! instead of calling it as a class method, call it as an instance method instead (see my updated code for the differences). the parameter for ```target:``` should be ```self``` instead of ```Sentence.self```

Comment: Yes I just saw that, excuse my negligence. It wouldn't make sense to pass `Sentence.self` when I was already in the context of a `Sentence` instance. Which, by the way, what would `Sentence.self` refer within a `Sentence` object? A static version of the object?

Comment: ```Sentence.self``` is the equivalent of ```[Sentence class]``` in ObjC. you would use it to call class methods (called type methods in Swift). recommend reading this for clarification of type vs instance methods: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html